# Custom Credential Providers and Remote Desktop Sessions

Tags: c#, authentication, remote-desktop, credential-providers

So I have developed a custom authentication provider that, (to greatly simplify things) replaces the current users password with one that is unknown to them and entirely random.  During the authentication process and with some wizzy crypto, the password is regenerated and passed through the Kerberos authentication process in replacement of any password they may have entered themselves (that is ignored).  I can't go into too much detail of how it all works but it does, locally anyway.  The idea is to use it on a machine in the cloud running Windows Server 2012, but I am experiencing issues and have come across this article,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/rdc-and-custom-credential-providers.aspx

According to this, non-Microsoft credential providers are supported, and that's true, it displays my credential provider albeit through a different looking UI.  It also states that after my credential provider has finished it will prompt to login again, using the users username and password.

Of course that can't happen in this context as the user doesn't know their password and never will.  Plus for some reason, it doesn't give me a second prompt anyway, the remote desktop window just closes when my authentication provider completes and an error is written into the event log suggesting of an unknown user or bad password.  Neither of those should be correct, and as stated this provider works 100% of the time locally, so I know it's working and have done extensive debugging on it.

So my question is, I guess, is there any way that I can achieve what I am after?  Even through hacking, and doing things that aren't generally done?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you want to change peoples' passwords to an unknown password when they rdp onto a server? is there a legit use for this?

Comment: Yes, there is a very legit use to this, as I said, I'm not going to explain the crypto behind it.  The administrator sets it up in the first place, it's not some automated hack.

Comment: Just to note, I can get it working fine using SplashTop, just not RDP.  Just testing it again but logged in twice in a row no sweat.

Comment: just to add another comment on your comment, just to clarify, no the users password is not changed upon login.  It's changed when the administrator runs a special setup utility and performs a number of tasks before they then go ahead with setting their password.

Comment: ah so it's more of a user password reset tool. sounded more sinister when i read it first.

Comment: yeah it's not sinister honest! haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the quickest, simplest solution for me was to install SplashTop streamer on the server and connect using SplashTop as opposed to RDP.  This brings up the local-style login UI which then works exactly how I desired.  It does cost $2 a month but that's hardly bank-breaking.

Comment: Why is this down voted?  This simply can't be done any other way, this is a way to get a working solution.  If you don't like it, say why or give another suggestion.

Comment: Voted it to zero. Do not understand the downvote on that answer :/